# Code doesn't compile on Hackerrank

Tags: java

The following code works fine on my IDE but I keep getting a "Compile Time Error" when I add it to Hackerrank. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.next();
        System.out.println(delete(input));
    }

    public static int delete(String in){
        char[] arr = in.toCharArray();
        int del = 0;
        for(int x=0; x < arr.length-1; x++){
            if(arr[x] == arr[x+1]){
                del++;
            }
        }
        return del;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it give you a compilation error? If so please post it

Comment: @nhouser9 No, all I get is "Compile Time Error" in red.

Comment: Your solution works fine even tested it in NetBeans so there is something else wrong here.

Comment: Can you post the link to the HackerRank challenge your code is for?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in Intellij too. But there is a wrong exist. Both main and delete methods are static. You use 'in' for both methods. Therefore just change the name of the string in delete method.